# The infamous object bug

Tags: java

I discovered what i think is a bug whilst using netbeans. When i call up my method to sort an array containing names(ob.sort) in alphabetical order it automatically sorts another array which contains the original names when it isn't supposed to as the original names is not assigned to anything after it has been populated with input at the beginning(ob.input).
I experienced this problem whilst writing larger programs(encountered more than once), but i made a simpler one to demonstrate this problem. It looks like much as i copied the class methods an pasted it below the main class making it easier for you to trace the variables in the program.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    ObjectTest ob = new ObjectTest();
    ob.input();
    String x[] = ob.getNames();
    System.out.println(x[0]);
    ob = new ObjectTest(x);
    System.out.println(x[0]);
    ob.sort();
    System.out.println(x[0]);
    String y[] = ob.getNamesrt();
    System.out.println(x[0]);

}
}
    /*import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class ObjectTest {
String name[];
String namesrt[];

public ObjectTest(){
    name = new String[3];
    namesrt = new String[3];
}

public ObjectTest(String j[]){
    namesrt = j;
}

public void input(){
    for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
        name[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name");
    }
}

public void sort(){
    if(!(namesrt == null)){
    for(int i = 0; i < namesrt.length; i++){
        for(int c = i + 1; c < namesrt.length; c++){
            if(namesrt[i].compareToIgnoreCase(namesrt[c]) > 0){
                String n = namesrt[i];
                namesrt[i] = namesrt[c];
                namesrt[c] = n;
            }
        }
    }
    }
    else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Names not received");}
}

public String[] getNames(){
    return name;
}

public String[] getNamesrt(){
    return namesrt;
}

public void setNames(String j[]){
    name = j;
}

public void setNamesrt(String j[]){
      namesrt = j;
}
}*/
```

Comment: Here's a useful link. Read about it, it's quite cool. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger

Comment: Please provide a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem. Indent it properly, and don't comment most of it out. Unless you think the problem is GUI-specific, you shouldn't need a GUI to demonstrate it - hard-code the data.

Comment: Well...it looks like you're passing around/using the same array in the class, and if you sort one array, it will be visible on the other one.  I don't have time to formally trace it, but note that arrays are mutable.

Comment: (And in what way is anything about this question "infamous"?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I discovered what i think is a bug whilst using netbeans.

Well, it may be a bug in your code. It's not a bug in Java or in Netbeans. It's just demonstrating the fact that arrays are reference types in Java, and the way that objects work.

Here's a short but complete program demonstrating the same effect:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] x = { "hello" };
        // Copy the *reference*
        String[] y = x;
        System.out.println(y[0]); // Prints "hello"
        x[0] = "new value";
        System.out.println(y[0]); // Prints "new value"
    }
}
```

The values of `x` and `y` here are *references* to the same array object... so if the array is changed "through" `x`, that change is still visible as `y[0]`.

If you want to make your code create *independent* objects, you'll want to change this:

```
public ObjectTest(String j[]){
    namesrt = j;
}
```

to:

```
public ObjectTest(String j[]){
    namesrt = j.clone();
}
```

(Ideally change it to declare the parameter as `String[] j`, or better yet fix all your variable names to be more meaningful, but that's a different matter.)